# Returning a 200 with also information on malformed objects when passing in a collection

Tags: c#, web-api

If I may jump straight into it.

I have a web api endpoint where I pass in a collection and it works amazingly but with one caveat.

If one object in that collection contains malformed data (missing required data) it returns a bad request, thus voiding the whole collection - the normal shenanigans but tech lead suggested allow the good ones to come through but return details of the "bad one" - well in terms of http requests, this is impossible, you cannot send an `Ok` and `BadRequest` simultaneously...

I've opted to pass in collections to save on resource rather than hitting the api multiple times for each order.

What I've done is abstracted out the "good" orders and pass those to another api, which then returns a 200 -

now I'm deliberating over what to do with the malformed ones - send a message in the 200 with malformed ones? or email the client of unsuccessful orders ... a nice issue to have. Any advice?

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("orders")]
    [DocMethod(Verb = "POST",
        Description = "Inserts a complete collection of order objects (Inclusive of related objects)",
        EndPoint = "/api/v1/orders",
        Version = "V1")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody]List<Order> orders)
    {
        var validatedOrders = FilterOrders.Validated(orders);

        if (orders == null && validatedOrders == null)
            return BadRequest("Unusable resources.");

        try
        {
            var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

            var identityModel = IdentityModel.Create(identity);
            if (identityModel == null)
                return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);

            var response = await _orderService.AddAsync(validatedOrders, identityModel);

            return new DataAPIResult(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result, response);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }   
    }
```

So, I technically don't have a code error(hence posting here) but more just an engineering process. Any Advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Return a 200 and a list of items that were not processed.  If the items are not processed immediately return a 202:accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how you want to manage your data. You can treat the inserts either transactionally or non-transactionally and they both present different advantages depending on the task.

If you are doing non-transactional processing and are fine with inserting only some of the bulk insert responding with a `200 Ok` along with error messages is acceptable and standard practice.

A typical response would be.

```
200 OK
Content-type: application/json
[
    {
        "index": 1,
        "status": "error",
        "messages": [
            "The item can't be added because of the error #22"
        ]
    },
    {
        "index": 2,
        "status": "success",
        "id": "<generated-id>"
    },
    (...)
]
```

If you want to treat the bulk requests transactionally you would respond with a `422 Unprocessable Entity` when there are validation errors, or a `500 Internal Server` error if an internal issue prevents recording the data. In both error cases, you would rollback any inserted items and respond with a list of validation / error messages.

```
422 Unprocessable Entity
Content-type: application/json
[
    {
        "index": 1,
        "messages": [
            {
                "email": "Must contain an @."
             }
        ]
    },
]
```

There are two additional solutions that are slightly more complex:

1. Respond with `202 Accepted` and a transaction id that may be polled for updates.
2. Using WebHooks, which involves creating an API on the client that could receive notifications from the server.

In the end, it comes down to how risk tolerant you are. If you are saving user transactions for a financial system failing the entire batch would be far safer. However, if you are inserting system metrics losing a few results will likely have very little impact.

Comment: I was actually just considering this option, as also returning a 207. But if this is the favoured approach then so be it. Slightly apprehensive due to knowing it contains malformed data. Anyhow greatly appreciate the nudge in the right direction.